# Saving plots with "≤" and "≥" symbols in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a strange problem:

I am working on a plot that in a legend text contains "≥" symbol. For example, `"x ≥ 2"`. Interestingly, the symbol appears correctly when I plot it using the R graphic device, but it appears incorrectly when I save it as PDF or EPS.

Any suggestions how can I save it in PDF / EPS correctly?

Comment: I can't even get `x ≥ 2` to appear properly in R. What OS and programs are you using specifically? (e.g. - RStudio?)

Comment: Works on a Mac (using an expression vector, of course). I don't know why it would be different in RStudio, but if it is, then you should ask them about it.

Comment: I use a modern distro of Linux, no RStudio, just a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're using a mac?

Use `cairo_pdf` instead of `pdf`:

```
> cairo_pdf("tmp.pdf")
> plot(2:10, xlab="x ≥ 2")
> dev.off()
null device 
          1
```

[image]

Comment: I use Linux, but `cairo_pdf` did the job anyway. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Are you adding the symbol using an expression and the relevant `?plotmath` markup? I suspect the problem is that you've literally used the "≥" glyph in the legend text. That will only work if you set the `encoding` correctly (see `?pdf`), and then that may not work well everywhere.

Doing this va plotmath should be portable:

```
plot(1:10)
legend("topleft",
       legend = c(expression(x >= 2), expression(x <= 1)),
       pch = 1:2)
```

Comment: Nice. Is there any downside to using say `legend("topright",legend="x \u2265 2")` instead? Other than clarity, which `expression` definitely has.

Comment: Only that as that is UTF8, it may not work well in locales not using UTF8. IIRC these glyphs in plotmath use the symbol font which is reasonably portable and reliable, but it doesn't cover every conceivable glyph. In the past I've had to resort to setting the encoding to use a per mille symbol for example.

Comment: This did not work for me because I am getting `unexpected input in "expression...` notification. I suppose what I am trying to write is not an expression and that's why. Anyway, cairo_pdf did the job. I use Linux.

Comment: @Oposum Show me the expression you used. The code above *does* work and should be portable, hence is preferred.